# Get protein annotation from Uniprot out of protein mappings

Tags: gene-annotation, proteomics

Having a file of for about 10k mapping identifiers how can I get the annotations of the proteins from Uniprot  ? As it is not possible to do It manually

My mappings are contained in a .csv file 
They are from STRING database Example 9606.ENSP00000387699

Comment: Can you please expand on this. What format are your ID's in (csv, excel, etc.)? And what is a mapping identifier, a uniprot accession, some other id? Lastly, Uniprot has a [batch download system here](http://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists/), which may suit your needs.

Comment: @emilliman5 I edited the question , they are contained in csv file , and they are  stringdb external identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is discussed [here](https://techoverflow.net/2013/11/20/mapping-string-aliases-to-uniprot-ids/). Apparently STRING IDs are in KEGG format but these can be mapped on to Uniprot IDs using information downloadable [from here](http://string-db.org/cgi/download.pl?UserId=0EY5iQrIGjtd&sessionId=CfgwKeGjLbaR). I guess that it is either the *protein.aliases* data or the *mapping_files* data that you would need. The first link provides a Python script to extract useful info from the downloaded data. These are big downloads so I haven't actually tried this out myself.

Presumably once you have the STRING→Uniprot conversion done you can query Uniprot with the output as a batch request.

Good luck!

Comment: @AM please comment again when you know if it worked out. Or even write your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

UniProt's batch download system, suggested by Alan Boyd above, also allows you to directly *map* identifiers, e.g. STRING to UniProtKB, or Ensembl to UniProtKB:
http://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists

Once you have your UniProtKB results, you can add or remove columns by clicking on "Columns", and once you are happy, you can download the results in tab-separated format (http://www.uniprot.org/help/customize).